# Is this proof about functions correct?

Tags: calculus

Did I do this proof correctly? You'll see why I think it is a little shaky in a minute:

Problem: Let E be a function satisfying $E(0)=E'(0)=1$. Prove that if $E(a+b)=E(a)E(b)$ for all $a,b$, then $E$ is differentiable and $E'(x)=E(x)$ for all x.

Let $E(x)=y$ and $E'(x)=dy/dx$

- $E(x+a)=E(x)*E(a)\ldots$
- $E(x+a)-E(x)=E(x)(E(a)-1)\ldots$
- $\lim_{a\to0} E(x+a)-E(x)=\lim_{a\to 0}E(x)(E(a)-1)\ldots$
- $dy=E(x)\cdot \lim_{a\to 0}(E(a)-1)\ldots$
- Since $E(0)=1$, then $\lim_{a\to0}(E(a)-1)=dy$. Since $E'(0)=1$, $dy$ is approximately equal to $dx\ldots$
- $dy=E(x)dx$
- $dy/dx=E(x)$
- $E'(x)=E(x)$

My math teacher skimmed over it and said it is ok, but I still have a feeling it is wrong because of the step which converts $(E(a)-1)$ to $dx$. The problem I see here is that instead of $dy=E(x)dx$ I could have just said $dy=E(x)dy$, so $E(x)=1$ which is clearly wrong. Any commentary is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to format your question a bit better, it's really hard to read like this. Also, this has nothing to do with number theory.

Comment: The math teacher is being *very* kind. There are a lot of naked $dx$ and $dy$ floating around, a very clear sign of lack of precision. At a certain stage you say let $E(x)=y$, then $E'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$. At best this change of notation does nothing. But you are really building in an assumption that the derivative exists, which is precisely what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like all that $dx$ and $dy$ they are confusing me here (maybe it is just the formatting), just use the definition of differentiable:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{E(x+h)-E(x)}{h}$$ 
exists.  With $E(a+b)=E(a)\cdot E(b)$ you get
$$\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{E(x+h)-E(x)}{h}=E(x) \lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{E(h)-1}{h} = E(x) \cdot 
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{E(h)-E(0)}{h}= E(x) \cdot E'(0)= E(x)$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thanks very much for your answer. Mine is pretty similar at least up to a point but yours is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Andre, altough with this I was only focusing on trying to prove that E(x) =E'(x)